# Intuition on random measurement matrix with non-adaptive linear measurements

Tags: matrices, measure-theory, intuition, sampling-theory, compression

Recently, I came across the concept of measuring a signal $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ via a measurement matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, where one has the linear system $y=Ax$ with $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ as the measured vector. In other words, I have a signal $x$ that I want to sample randomly (e.g., with Gaussian distribution) by applying $A$ and obtaining my $m$ measurements in the vector $y$ (let's say $m<n$). How can I think of this measurement process, as $A$ is random and therefore each measured sample is like a linear combination of $x$ with a row of $A$?

Without the mathematics involved I would just think about a (let's say a sine wave) signal/function where I obtain some function values at different (random) times. But I am confused in the case where I would apply $A$ for the measurement as I would not get the information of one time stamp but rather a combination of all of them. So how is this still related to random sampling (I want to get an intuition), i.e., how would one in practice obtain those measurements?

Any intuition for imaging how this process would look is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you been reading on compressed sensing?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes I was reading on compressed sensing. And there are multiple images showing how the sampling is done by selecting random points of for example an signal in time domain. But afterwards everybody talks about random matrices, but I don't really get the connection how this should still mean selecting random points of the signal. So in a practical way, how are the random measurements acquired by applying random matrix $A$ connected with sampling in practise?

Comment: Have you read Terry Tao's [Compressed sensing and single-pixel cameras](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/04/13/compressed-sensing-and-single-pixel-cameras)?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo no I haven't read it up until now. Thanks for the reference! Still it is pretty hard to understand that totally. But I will try to do so. If there are still other intuitions and insights, please let me know! Thank you!

Comment: Aren't you forgetting that $A x = y$ is underdetermined?  There should be infinitely many solutions — the solution set should be a hyperplane.  However, we are looking for **sparse** solutions. Thus, the 1-norm minimization.

Comment: If you have 10 minutes, take a look at [what Maryam Fazel has to say about it](https://youtu.be/lXeEWsJ_5TQ?t=656)

Comment: A famous paper is [Single-pixel imaging via compressive sampling](https://doi.org/10.1109/MSP.2007.914730) (2008)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thanks for the resources! It now makes more sense. I guess I will have to get used to that one might not be able to translate every mathematical object in a practical one. Thanks!